# Find the number of items in $10000$ sets of 10 throws each in which you would expect no even numbers.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given to us is that we have an irregular six-faced die and the expectation that in $10$ throws, $5$ even numbers show up is twice the expectation that $4$ even numbers show up.
The question( as in the title) is:
"How many items in $10000$ sets of $10$ throws each, would one expect no even numbers?"

What I did:
I assumed a binomial model and then I equated the probabilities of $5$ and $4$ even numbers respectively. It gave me the probability of success as $\frac{5}{8}$.
I don't really understand how to proceed further.
Please help.

Comment: I agree p(even) gives p(5 even)=2*p(4 even). Now what is the chance in one set of 10 throws you get no evens?  Then multiply by 10000 to get the expected value.

Comment: @ross millikan: okay i got it.

Comment: You could write up the answer and (after a wait) accept it so this doesn't stay unanswered

Comment: Will do that soon

Answer (score 0):

Given n = 10, calculate p = probability of getting an even number.
As you calculated it to be 5/8,

So p = 5/8, q = (1-p) = 3/8.

Now according to the question, we need to find how many sets out of 10000 sets would produce odd outputs only like (1,3,5)?
This means no evens i.e. P[X=0].

So the answer for the problem would be **10000*P[X=0] = 1**(approx)